# Bootstrap row Class Causes Padding to Hang Over

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, grid, row

if you look at [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tlbaxter99/za0rsb43/5/), you'll notice the second paragraph (with green background) seems to have its padding "hang over" to the left. This seems to be caused by the fact that the paragraph is wrapped in a `<div class="row>`.  My impression was that `class='row'` simply started a new row in a grid. I'm wondering about this odd effect of the left padding hanging out, relative to the previous and next paragraphs.

Comment: .row {   margin-right: -15px;   margin-left: -15px; } these are the rules for the row class and why you see the behavior. See (Docs)[http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-intro] about the grid structure.

Comment: This is in order to make the grid system work, and the column classes take this into account and adjust. Place your content within a div with one or more column classes inside the row, rather than directly in the row.

Comment: If you want to have 12 columns you don't have to use row class (just add div in container), but if you create a row in container you have to use `col-*` classes provided by Bootstrap (`col-md-12` class in your case).